# how to get KeyEvent handled in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have tests about KeyEvent in javafx,if I use onKeyPressed() method bound to any kind of pane,it wouldn't work.bound to scene or a button would work fine.I am wondering how can I let pane associated with KeyEvent.

Comment: You need to make sure the pane has the focus or one of it's descendants has the focus and no node on the path to the pane consumes the event. `Pane`s by default are not [elligible to receive the focus.](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty)

Answer (score 2):

To add key events handlers to pane effectively you need to request focus on pane first.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PanesKeyEventsApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        StackPane stackPane1 = new StackPane();
        stackPane1.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        stackPane1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: purple;");

        StackPane stackPane2 = new StackPane();
        stackPane2.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        stackPane2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");

        HBox hBox = new HBox(stackPane1, stackPane2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        stackPane1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> stackPane1.requestFocus());
        stackPane2.setOnMouseClicked(event -> stackPane2.requestFocus());

        stackPane1.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> System.out.println("purple key pressed " + event.getCode()));
        stackPane2.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> System.out.println("yellow key pressed " + event.getCode()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.In fact,I am using fxml to build a game,my data and my functions are in my controller.class,and the scene is created in the start().so my problem is that I can't move all my logic to this main method.Can you help me solve it?

Comment: <pre><code>FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("GameView.fxml"));
            AnchorPane anchorPane = loader.load();
            scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
            scene.getRoot().requestFocus();<pre><code>  currently I wrote like this,but it won't work

Comment: @刘希晨You must just learn more about fxml and proper usage. Solution I proposed just gives a basic idea. Combining it with fxml is of course possible but out of the scope of current question.

Comment: I determined to use pure code to rebuild this UI.  fxml is very slow according to my research.So this won't be a problem.I find out that most people just don't use fxml,is this the reason?

Comment: @刘希晨Fxml is not the reason. Fxml gives you ability to separate a big chunk of view. I would really recommend to use it. Imo what you are suppose to do is: connect your fxml with controller (google it). In controller class use FXML annotation to bind your pane with fxml pane. After your view is shown to the user make sure to call requestFocus() method. The crucial part is: "after shown to the user", because I have some doubts if you can effectively request focus on not rendered view.

Comment: Thank you!I finally solved it.You are really helpful!